# How to modify this code so that the second scanf() executes?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100], search[100]; 
    printf("Enter a string ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
    printf("\n Enter search substring ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",search);
}
```

When I run the above code, the first `scanf()` does execute and takes user input. However, it skips over the second `scanf()` and ends the program.

I think this happens because the second `scanf()` finds `\n` in the buffer (from previous input) and stops. What can I do to correct this behaviour?

Comment: `s` should not be a part of the format `%[^\n]`. It is usually `%s` or `%[^\n]`.

Comment: Yes ^^ look at that answer.  But the big problem with this code is that you will get a buffer overrun if the user enters more than 100 characters.  I suggest using fgets() to read the input, rather than scanf.  And then `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` to strip the newline.